# Decode HTML Entities in VBA using regex and dictionary

Tags: html, vba, regex, hash-map

I receive HTML-encoded text that includes named and numbered entities, and I need the decoded HTML.

There were just too many [bad](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?591224-RESOLVED-Html-entities-coding-decoding-vb6&p=4664183&viewfull=1#post4664183) solutions for this online.

I use regex pattern `&(#x|#){0,1}(\w{1,8});` to find the entities in an HTML text (capturing the numeric prefix and the numeric expression), and I use a `Static` `Scripting.Dictionary` to look up a (case-sensitive) named entity's decimal encoding. It's `Static` because this is the type of function that can get called multiple times, so I only set up the dictionary once.

I then assemble the result using array assignments and a final `Join` function to avoid unnecessary concatenation. I could *probably* eek better performance by using the `Mid` statement to progressively fill a `String` buffer.

First the function itself:

### HTMLDecode

```
Public Function HTMLDecode(ByRef sourceText As String) As String

  Const PROC_NAME As String = "HTMLDecode"

  Const VB_HEX_PREFIX As String = "&h"
  Const DEC_CHARACTER_REFERENCE_PREFIX As String = "#"
  Const HEX_CHARACTER_REFERENCE_PREFIX As String = "#x"

  Dim characterReferences As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
  Set characterReferences = ExtractCharacterReferences(sourceText)

  Static namedEntities As Scripting.Dictionary
  If namedEntities Is Nothing Then
    Set namedEntities = CreateEntityDictionary
  End If

  Dim currentPosition As Long
  Dim nextPosition As Long
  Dim characterReference As Match

  currentPosition = 1
  Dim refCounter As Long

  ReDim resultParts(characterReferences.Count * 2) As String
  For Each characterReference In characterReferences
    nextPosition = characterReference.FirstIndex
    Dim character As String
    Dim refText As String
    refText = characterReference.SubMatches.Item(1)
    If namedEntities.Exists(refText) Then
      'characterReference is a named entity
      character = ChrW$(namedEntities.Item(refText))
    Else
      'characterReference is probably a numeric entity
      Select Case characterReference.SubMatches.Item(0)
        Case DEC_CHARACTER_REFERENCE_PREFIX
          If IsNumeric(refText) Then
            'entity is a decimal codepoint
            character = ChrW$(CLng(refText))
          Else
            Err.Raise ERROR_UNEXPECTED_ENTITY_FORMAT, PROC_NAME, "Unexpected decimal entity value '" & characterReference.Value & "'"
          End If
        Case HEX_CHARACTER_REFERENCE_PREFIX
          Dim hexRefText As String
          hexRefText = VB_HEX_PREFIX & refText
          If IsNumeric(hexRefText) Then
            'entity is a hex codepoint
            character = ChrW$(CLng(hexRefText))
          Else
            Err.Raise ERROR_UNEXPECTED_ENTITY_FORMAT, PROC_NAME, "Unexpected hex entity value '" & characterReference.Value & "'"
          End If
        Case Else
          'Unexpected entity text
          Err.Raise ERROR_UNEXPECTED_ENTITY_FORMAT, PROC_NAME, "Unexpected entity name '" & characterReference.Value & "'"
      End Select
    End If
    resultParts(refCounter) = Mid(sourceText, currentPosition, nextPosition - currentPosition + 1)
    resultParts(refCounter + 1) = character
    currentPosition = nextPosition + characterReference.Length + 1
    refCounter = refCounter + 2
  Next characterReference

  'Catch any text trailing the last entity
  If currentPosition <= Len(sourceText) Then
    resultParts(refCounter) = Mid$(sourceText, currentPosition)
  End If
  HTMLDecode = Join(resultParts, vbNullString)

End Function
```

And the helper constants/functions in the same module:

### HTMLHelpers.bas

```
Option Explicit

Private Const ERROR_UNEXPECTED_ENTITY_COUNT As Long = vbObjectError Or 1
Private Const ERROR_UNEXPECTED_ENTITY_DUPLICATE As Long = vbObjectError Or 2
Private Const ERROR_UNEXPECTED_ENTITY_VALUE As Long = vbObjectError Or 3
Private Const ERROR_UNEXPECTED_ENTITY_FORMAT As Long = vbObjectError Or 4

Private Function CreateEntityDictionary() As Scripting.Dictionary

  Const PROC_NAME As String = "getEntityDictionary"

  Const ENTITY_NAMES = _
    "quot,amp,apos,lt,gt,nbsp,iexcl,cent,pound,curren,yen,brvbar,sect,uml,copy,ordf," & _
    "laquo,not,shy,reg,macr,deg,plusmn,sup2,sup3,acute,micro,para,middot,cedil,sup1,ordm," & _
    "raquo,frac14,frac12,frac34,iquest,Agrave,Aacute,Acirc,Atilde,Auml,Aring,AElig,Ccedil,Egrave,Eacute,Ecirc," & _
    "Euml,Igrave,Iacute,Icirc,Iuml,ETH,Ntilde,Ograve,Oacute,Ocirc,Otilde,Ouml,times,Oslash,Ugrave,Uacute," & _
    "Ucirc,Uuml,Yacute,THORN,szlig,agrave,aacute,acirc,atilde,auml,aring,aelig,ccedil,egrave,eacute,ecirc," & _
    "euml,igrave,iacute,icirc,iuml,eth,ntilde,ograve,oacute,ocirc,otilde,ouml,divide,oslash,ugrave,uacute," & _
    "ucirc,uuml,yacute,thorn,yuml,OElig,oelig,Scaron,scaron,Yuml,fnof,circ,tilde,Alpha,Beta,Gamma," & _
    "Delta,Epsilon,Zeta,Eta,Theta,Iota,Kappa,Lambda,Mu,Nu,Xi,Omicron,Pi,Rho,Sigma,Tau," & _
    "Upsilon,Phi,Chi,Psi,Omega,alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,zeta,eta,theta,iota,kappa,lambda," & _
    "mu,nu,xi,omicron,pi,rho,sigmaf,sigma,tau,upsilon,phi,chi,psi,omega,thetasym,upsih," & _
    "piv,ensp,emsp,thinsp,zwnj,zwj,lrm,rlm,ndash,mdash,lsquo,rsquo,sbquo,ldquo,rdquo,bdquo," & _
    "dagger,Dagger,bull,hellip,permil,prime,Prime,lsaquo,rsaquo,oline,frasl,euro,image,weierp,real,trade," & _
    "alefsym,larr,uarr,rarr,darr,harr,crarr,lArr,uArr,rArr,dArr,hArr,forall,part,exist,empty," & _
    "nabla,isin,notin,ni,prod,sum,minus,lowast,radic,prop,infin,ang,and,or,cap,cup," & _
    "int,there4,sim,cong,asymp,ne,equiv,le,ge,sub,sup,nsub,sube,supe,oplus,otimes," & _
    "perp,sdot,lceil,rceil,lfloor,rfloor,lang,rang,loz,spades,clubs,hearts,diams"

  Const ENTITY_VALUES = _
    "34,38,39,60,62,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170," & _
    "171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186," & _
    "187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202," & _
    "203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218," & _
    "219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234," & _
    "235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250," & _
    "251,252,253,254,255,338,339,352,353,376,402,710,732,913,914,915," & _
    "916,917,918,919,920,921,922,923,924,925,926,927,928,929,931,932," & _
    "933,934,935,936,937,945,946,947,948,949,950,951,952,953,954,955," & _
    "956,957,958,959,960,961,962,963,964,965,966,967,968,969,977,978," & _
    "982,8194,8195,8201,8204,8205,8206,8207,8211,8212,8216,8217,8218,8220,8221,8222," & _
    "8224,8225,8226,8230,8240,8242,8243,8249,8250,8254,8260,8364,8465,8472,8476,8482," & _
    "8501,8592,8593,8594,8595,8596,8629,8656,8657,8658,8659,8660,8704,8706,8707,8709," & _
    "8711,8712,8713,8715,8719,8721,8722,8727,8730,8733,8734,8736,8743,8744,8745,8746," & _
    "8747,8756,8764,8773,8776,8800,8801,8804,8805,8834,8835,8836,8838,8839,8853,8855," & _
    "8869,8901,8968,8969,8970,8971,9001,9002,9674,9824,9827,9829,9830"

  Const ENTITY_DELIMITER As String = ","

  Set CreateEntityDictionary = New Scripting.Dictionary
  'Entity names must be case sensitive
  CreateEntityDictionary.CompareMode = BinaryCompare

  Dim entityNames() As String
  entityNames = Split(ENTITY_NAMES, ENTITY_DELIMITER)

  Dim entityValues() As String
  entityValues = Split(ENTITY_VALUES, ENTITY_DELIMITER)

  If UBound(entityNames) = UBound(entityValues) Then
    With CreateEntityDictionary
      Dim entityCounter As Long
      For entityCounter = LBound(entityNames) To UBound(entityNames)
        If Not .Exists(entityNames(entityCounter)) Then
          If IsNumeric(entityValues(entityCounter)) Then
            .Add entityNames(entityCounter), CLng(entityValues(entityCounter))
          Else
            Err.Raise ERROR_UNEXPECTED_ENTITY_VALUE, PROC_NAME, "Unexpected entity value: " & entityValues(entityCounter)
          End If
        Else
          Err.Raise ERROR_UNEXPECTED_ENTITY_DUPLICATE, PROC_NAME, "Unexpected duplicate entity name: " & entityNames(entityCounter)
        End If
      Next entityCounter
    End With
  Else
    Err.Raise ERROR_UNEXPECTED_ENTITY_COUNT, PROC_NAME, "Unexpected number of entity names/values"
  End If

End Function

Private Function ExtractCharacterReferences(ByRef sourceText As String) As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection

  Const REFERENCE_PATTERN As String = "&(#{0,1}[x]{0,1})(\w{1,8});"

  With New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = REFERENCE_PATTERN
    Set ExtractCharacterReferences = .Execute(sourceText)
  End With

End Function
```

### Example Usage

```
?htmlhelpers.HTMLDecode("&quot;,&amp;,&apos;,&lt;,&gt;,&nbsp;,&iexcl;,&cent;,&pound;,&curren;")
",&,',<,>, ,¡,¢,£,¤

?htmlhelpers.HTMLDecode("Bill&#xa0;&amp;&#x000000A0;Ted&#apos;s&#160;Excellent&#00000160;Adventure")
Bill & Ted's Excellent Adventure
```

---

### More Information:

- Wikipedia : [**List of XML and HTML character entity references**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)
- Wikipedia : [**Character Encodings in HTML**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML)

### Related:

- Wikipedia : [**Escape Characters** in JavaScript, etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#JavaScript)
- Wikipedia : [**SGML entity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SGML_entity)

Comment: huh, just tested `"&xi;"` and it fails because my regex is careless about catching the numeric prefix.

Comment: Corrected regex from `&(#{0,1}[x]{0,1})(\w{1,8});` to `&(#x|#){0,1}(\w{1,8});` and fixed `&xi;` problem

Comment: I guess that would be better still, as `&(#x|#)?(\w{1,8});`

Comment: `Dim characterReference as Match` - what's a match type?

Comment: @Raystafarian That's a `VBScript_RegExp_55.Match`

Comment: @ThunderFrame - OMG, I feel like I've been looking for this *forever*.  Thank you.

Comment: Looking at your example, why would `Ted&#apos;s` decode to `Ted's`? The html entity is incorrect?